# NameError: name 'funt1' is not defined [while running 'format data-ptransform-40']

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am running dataflow pipeline to load into biqquery but I am getting the below error

```
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)]
```

> File "/home/mprabakaran/mergefile.py", line 93, in <lambda>
> NameError: name 'funt1' is not defined [while running 'format data-ptransform-40']

I defined the function 'funt1'  as below in my code

```
def funt1(row):
    data={}
    data['ID']=row[0]
    if row[1]['gender']:
        data['gender']=row[1]['gender'][0]
    else:
        data['gender']=None
    if row[1]['weight']:
        data['weight']=row[1]['weight'][0]
    else:
        data['weight']=''      
    #print(data)
    return data
```

below is the part of pipeline code

```
       data = (({'gender': gender_data, 'weight': weight_data})
                | 'Merge' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
                | 'format data' >> beam.Map(lambda x: funt1(x)) | beam.Map(print) )
        beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec2,
            dataset="nyb_data",
            project="toyota-poc-340710",
            # known_args.output,
            # schema='id:INTEGER,gender:STRING,wieght:STRING',
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
            )
```

not sure what I am missing. Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the Python module that contains the function `funt1` is packaged and staged in Dataflow VMs so that it's available during runtime. Please see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#local-or-nonpypi) for instructions.

Another option is to set [save_main_session](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/4dddaf9c3d70b5b858c16265abee4cdbf0c72631/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L1129) option which results in the main session (including functions loaded to session) available to workers, but this might not work for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined the `funt1` function in the class and called as below.

| 'format data' >> beam.Map(lambda x: **dataingestion**.funt1(x)) | beam.Map(print) )

here dataingestion is class. It worked for me. Thanks for responding to my query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).